# Sorting the Child ItemSource in a Parent-Child Combobox ItemSource Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml

I have a User Control, that contains two combo box's, where users can select an inventory category and then select an inventory item. The inventory category combo box's selected value triggers the inventory item combo box list. The problem that I am having is that I can not sort the Inventory Items combo list. When I add the combined Inventory Category and Inventory Items to the DataContext I can sort the Inventory Category, however I can not sort the Inventory Items List. The code looks like this:

Xaml:

```
<ComboBox Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ComboBoxStyle}"
          Name="cboInventoryCategory"
          MinWidth="250"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.InventoryCategoryList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl,Mode=FindAncestor}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Category"
          SelectedValuePath="Id"
          SelectionChanged="cboInventoryCategory_SelectionChanged" />

<ComboBox Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ComboBoxStyle}"
          Name="cboInventoryItem"
          MinWidth="250"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cboInventoryCategory,Path=SelectedItem.InventoryLists}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Inventory_Id, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          DisplayMemberPath="InventoryDescription"
          SelectedValuePath="InventoryId"
          SelectionChanged="cboRequestFor_SelectionChanged" />
```

Xaml.CS:

```
public Inventory()
{
    Initialize();

    var db = new DataContext();
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();

    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

View Model:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;

public IEnumerable<InventoryCategory> InventoryCategoryList { get; set; }
//InventoryCategory is a table
//InventoryList is a view and has a primary key and an association in the dbml

public ViewModel()
{
    InventoryCategoryList_Refresh()
}

public void InventoryCategoryList_Refresh()
{

     var dataOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
     dataOptions.LoadWith<InventoryCategory>(ic => ic.InventoryLists);
     db.LoadOptions = dataOptions;

     InventoryCategoryList = db.InventoryCategories.Where(w => w.Active == true).OrderBy(o => o.Category);
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error?  If so, what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use .AssociateWith<> instead of .LoadWith<>

```
var dataOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
dataOptions.AssociateWith<InventoryCategory>(ic => ic.InventoryLists.OrderBy(o => o.InventoryDescription));
db.LoadOptions = dataOptions;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void InventoryCategoryList_Refresh()
{

     var dataOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
     dataOptions.LoadWith<InventoryCategory>(ic => ic.InventoryLists);
     db.LoadOptions = dataOptions;

     InventoryCategoryList = db.InventoryCategories.Where(w => w.Active == true).OrderBy(o => o.Category).ThenBy(c=>c.InventoryItems);
}
```

Comment: doing that gets me to the InventoryList, but errors. So I took it one deeper by setting a second order by but it still errored with "Cannot order by type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1DB.InventoryList'. The code looked like this InventoryCategoryList = db.InventoryCategories.Where(w => w.Active == true).OrderBy(o => o.Category).ThenBy(c=>c.InventoryList.OrderBy(a=>a.Description));

Comment: so if you do the ThenBy, do you get the same "Cannot order by type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1DB.InventoryList'  error?

Comment: If I try and set the order by when I set the .LoadWith() I get this error: The expression specified mest be of the form p.A, where p is the parameter and A is the property or field member. The code looks like this: dataOptions.LoadWith<InventoryCategory>(ic=>ic.InventoryLists.OrderBy(o=>o.InventoryDescription));

Comment: You have to use .AssociateWith<> instead of .LoadWith<> 

Previous code:

    dataOptions.LoadWith<InventoryCategory>(ic=>ic.InventoryLists.OrderBy(o=>o.InventoryDescription));

Code that works:

    dataOptions.AssociateWith<InventoryCategory>(ic=>ic.InventoryLists.OrderBy(o=>o.InventoryDescription));

Comment: Yep. The .LoadWith() is a straight load. Using the .AssociateWith() you can use the "query" properties (ie .Wher, .OrderBy, ect.) or so it appears so far....